# Trying to change a person's skin colour

Tags: ios, uiimage, pixel, skin

I am creating an app at the moment which take a picture of a person's face and I want to change the colour of their skin (just for fun!)

I have a piece of code that runs through the image pixel by pixel and finds the skin colour and then amends it to a new colour, which kind of works, but even though I am allowing for the differences in tones and adjusting the new colour in the same way it is still very hit and miss.

can anyone point me in the right direction?? is it even possible? I dont really want to use a filter as I dont think it would give the right effect.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at some computer vision techniques such as [segmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_%28image_processing) and [feature extraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_extraction).